# Fetch error (evaluating 'input.bodyUsed')

Tags: javascript, react-native

In the code below, I don't get the response and get an [undefined error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRDKz.png) instead.

[image: undefined error]

```
fetchData() {
  fetch(Global.user_list)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json()
      } 
    })
    .then((data) => {})
    .catch((err)=> {
      alert(err)
    })
}
```

Comment: You'll have to post what `Global.user_list` is. No way to tell what's wrong otherwise.

Comment: Please expand your code otherwise is hard to say.

Comment: Global.user_list is a request url, the request is fine,it response json in the browser

Comment: can anyone help me, thanks in advance

Comment: @user7871794 Just like mitogh said, you really have to expand on the code. Even providing the request URL will help because right now, there is no way to tell what kind of request is being made and what the response  received (and expected) looks like.

Answer (score 6):

I got the same exception by chance. I was doing a refactoring and failed to provide a valid url to the fetch function.

So I would recommend you check what is inside `Global.user_list` .

Comment: I had the same issue, the URL was the problem